# Unable to query SQL view

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working on an old classic ASP site and have run into a problem. I can query database tables but not views.

This query on a table returns the correct number of rows:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblContent;"
rs.Open sqlQuery, conn, 1, 2
response.write "q1 cnt = " & rs.RecordCount
```

The same query on a view returns `-1`:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM myView;"
rs.Open sqlQuery, conn, 1, 2
response.write "q2 cnt = " & rs.RecordCount
```

Both queries return the correct number of rows if run from SQL Server Management Studio but only one works when called from a `.asp` web page. The same seems to apply for all tables and views in the DB (I've tested half a dozen of so of each).

Can anyone offer any clues as to what is going on here?

Comment: One possible workaround is to count your rows at the SQL level.  You could have as your query `SELECT COUNT(*) as myrecordcount FROM myView`, and you could display the value with `rs("myrecordcount")`

Comment: @John: Thanks. I'm still puzzled by the above but your workaround does exactly what I need so if you make it an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: Note that the query of the view probably *does* return the correct rows; it's just the `.RecordCount` property that doesn't get the correct value. So another workaround is to stuff the results into an array (with `GetRows`) and then use `UBound()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's my comment as an answer

This is a workaround, it doesn't explain why the recordcount property doesn't work with views, but you can use an SQL query to count your rows, eg

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as myrecordcount FROM myView;"
rs.Open sqlQuery, conn, 1, 2
response.write "q2 cnt = " & rs("myrecordcount")
```

Answer (score -1):

You are requesting editable recordset which may fail on views. Try to open default forward-only read-only recordset

```
rs.Open sqlQuery, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

or

```
rs.Open sqlQuery, conn, 0, 1
```

Comment: Thanks but that still returns -1.

Comment: "The RecordCount property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor" (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx) so please delete this mis-information. (The up-voter should be ashamed)